# Regex Negative Lookahead using group defined earlier in match

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regex to parse a log file that's generated by several hundred of our routers. The log is a script that tries to ping each of the other routers in the environment. This is for compliance to prove that we can't ping each of the other routers in the environment. The logs look similar to the following excerpt (only much larger).

```
Interface Name = INTNET1
IP Address                     =   192.168.200.200,

---PING Section---
PING 192.168.200.200: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.200.200: icmp_seq=0. time=0. ms
64 bytes from 192.168.200.200: icmp_seq=1. time=0. ms
----192.168.200.200 PING Statistics----
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max = 0/0/0
no answer from 192.168.12.13
no answer from 192.168.151.1
no answer from 192.168.19.1
no answer from 192.168.84.1
64 bytes from 192.168.100.100: icmp_seq=0. time=0. ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.100: icmp_seq=1. time=0. ms
----192.168.100.100 PING Statistics----
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max = 0/0/0
```

Because all of the routers are listed in the script, each router will ping itself and receive a positive reply. Using this to gather the router's mgmt. IP:

```
IP\sAddress\s*\=\s*(?<MGMTIP>.*)
```

I want to negatively lookahead through the matches of the following pattern (the PING Statistics lines)

```
\-\-\-\-(.*)\-\-\-\-
```

and only match if it the address isn't a match with the named group.
I've been hacking away at it for a while now and just can't seem to make it work.

**EDIT:**
I wonder if I'm over-complicating this. All I really need out of this whole string block is to match any lines with this pattern:

```
\-\-\-\-(.*)\-\-\-\-
```

But only capture the '(.*)' part if it doesn't match Group 1 from this pattern (which matches the IP address of the host issuing the pings)

```
IP\sAddress\s*\=\s*(.*)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output, given your posted input?

Comment: Sure. I'd like to just get a match of all IP addresses on any line that has "----a.b.c.d PING Statistics----" that isn't a match to the named group "MGMTIP"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language you're using so I can't give an exact answer, but this is really difficult to do with a single pattern, so I suggest using 2. The first pattern you wrote will capture your IP.

`IP\sAddress\s*\=\s*(?<MGMTIP>.*)`

We'll save that to a variable called "myIP" (if you're really concerned about accuracy you'll want to escape each `.` in "myIP" because with regex `.` matches any character. Chances are this won't matter though)

Your next pattern should be `"(?s)----" + myIP + "\sPING\sStatistics----.*?(?=----\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\sPING\sStatistics----|\Z)"`

This will match every section that you *don't* want. You can replace any of those matches with `""` and it will leave you with all the sections you're looking for.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RsRdUZ/4)

Comment: It's for a Tripwire Enterprise deployment, which uses java (I model my stuff in pcre on regex101.com)

Comment: So for java, use `string.matches()` to capture the IP, and `string.replaceAll()` to remove the unwanted sections.

Comment: I think I forgot to include some important information. This regex isn't in use in a script or code; Tripwire only allows you to use regex as a filter; so you take a block of text and have to whittle it down to just the desired result. I'll admit to a bit of rookie'ism here, and forgive me if I ask for an example of how you'd use those 2 bits in a code sample.

Comment: So you absolutely need this in one pattern because of the filter specification?

Comment: Such a pattern will likely involve recursion and god knows what else. It is beyond me. You might want to check with [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew). He's quite the regex wizard.